# Java using Scanner as a parameter for a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

This is a question for a school assignment, which is why I am doing it in such a way.

Anyways, I make a scanner using Stdin in the main method (Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); is the line), reading data from a txt specified when the program is run. This Scanner works as expected in the main, however I need to use it in an custom class that has Scanner as an argument:

```
    public PhDCandidate(Scanner stdin)
    { 

    name = stdin.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name); //THIS NEVER RUNS
    preliminaryExams = new Exam[getNumberOfExams()];

    for(int i = 0; i <= getNumberOfExams(); i++)
    {
        preliminaryExams[i] = new Exam(stdin.nextLine(), stdin.nextDouble());
    }
    System.out.print("alfkj");
   }
```

At this point any call of the Scanner will just end the program, with no exceptions or errors thrown. Only calling .next() works. I could make the program work, but it would be hacky, and I really don't understand what is happening. I suspect I am missing a very simple concept, but I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "At this point any call of the Scanner will just end the program, with no exceptions or errors thrown." At what point exactly? Where in your code does the program end?

Comment: I don't think your program actually terminated. I think your console is waiting for the input instead. Try entering some name on the console.

Comment: @ Code-Guru: It ends whenever I try to use the Scanner (with the exception of stdin.next(), all other methords break), so immediately upon trying to use .nextLine()

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hey thank you for the help everyone. Turns out the problem was with the   Exam class, and the way Scanner works. What was happening was that when I was calling nextInt() in the main (as well as nextDouble() in the code shown), it reads the int (or double) but does NOT advance to the next line. This caused a subsequent nextLine() call to return an empty string as there was no content left, but the line the Scanner was on still had not advanced past a new line character, and every token in the txt was on a different line. S0 yes I stupid problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you are not closing and re-initializing `Scanner stdin` before calling constructor as I suspect that is the problem i.e. if you are doing something like below:

```
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        .........
        stdin.close(); //This will close your input stream(System.in) as well  

        .....
        .....

        stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        PhDCandidate phDCandidate = new PhDCandidate(stdin);
```

`stdin` inside the constructor will not read anything as input stream `System.in` is already closed.

Answer (score 1):

your code works fine for me. after creating the scanner in the main pass it as an argument.

```
 public Test(Scanner stdin)
        { 
System.out.println("enter something");
        name = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name); //THIS NEVER RUNS


        System.out.print("alfkj");
       }
    public  static void main(String...args)throws SQLException {
        new Test(new Scanner(System.in));
}

output: enter something
        xyzabc
        alfkj
```

Comment: The issue is that despite the System.in(), it is actually reading from a .txt file. If I am to replace the Scanner construction with Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"); The Scanner still operates in the same fasion.

Answer (score 1):

Add a set Name method in your PhDCandidate class.  This way you can create a PhDCandidate object inside your main method and print the name or do whatever from main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PhDCandidate c = new PhDCandidate();
    c.setName(stdin.nextLine());
}
```